# Get resources inside or outside constructor?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constructor

I need your opinion on writing a constructor that's clean code and unit test friendly.

Option 1 :

```
var res1 = bigObject.GetResource1();
var res2 = bigObject.GetResource2();
var res3 = bigObject.GetResource3();
var myObject = new Foo(bigObject, res1, res2, res3);
//and the foo ctor just initializes its internal fields with given data
```

Option 2 :

```
var myObject = new Foo(bigObject);
[...]
public Foo(Bar bigObject)
{
    _bigObject = bigObject;
    _res1 = _bigObject.GetResource1();
    _res2 = _bigObject.GetResource2();
    _res3 = _bigObject.GetResource3();
}
```

Option 2 is cleaner (?) in the code (in option 1 I have the feeling I have to spoon-feed the Foo object because it is not smart enough to get what it needs by itself)), but requires helper methods in the tests to mock calls to `Get*` and pass what we want.

Of course, I can also write both ctors, and use one in the tests and the other in the "real" code, but it'd looks a bit weird and bloated to someone discovering the class, and the simple constructor wouldn't be tested.

What would you advise ?

---

EDIT :

Resources are not especially linked to the big object (i.e. there is no "wrong" combination). Imagine for example that the big object is a College, and resources are a list of teachers, a list of courses and a list of rooms, and we want to build, say, a timetable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are these resources always linked to the `bigObject` instance? Do they have something in common with certain data or functionality in `bigObject`? Are they somehow related mutually? It's hard to say exactly what is the better approach without knowing all this, but there are several sanity checks you can do:

1. Do `GetResource1` to `GetResource3` really all depend on the `bigObject` instance? Can you extract this functionality into a different class? [Extract class](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/extract-class) refactoring might be an option.
2. Does `bigObject` know too much? Big kinda sounds like God, as in ["god object"](http://sourcemaking.com/antipatterns/the-blob).
3. If these three resources always come together (i.e. they all belong to the **same interface**), you might want to extract only them into a ["parameter object"](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/introduce-parameter-object). This means that you might end up with something in the middle, like:

   ```
   public Foo(Bar bigObject, IResources resources)
   {
      ...
   }
   ```

   Which means your `bigObject` will implement `IResources`, but you will also be able to implement them in a different way, and it will reduce the number of params.
4. If these resources are all of the same type, and there is a large number of them, then even a simple delegate might be enough. You might even want to make the call weakly typed for greater extensibility:

   ```
   public Foo(Bar bigObject, Func<string, IRes> getResourceByName)
   {
        var res1 = getResourceByName("1");
        var res2 = getResourceByName("2");
        ...
   }
   ```

These suggestions popped out as I was writing, but ultimately, it's hard to give any exact guidance unless you state the actual problem you are trying to solve. Design should then follow from there.

Comment: I don't like the weak typing suggestion. Especially since each resource is most likely used in a different way, which would mean adding casts.

Comment: my big object is indeed close to a god object, but it's not my line to refactor this.

Comment: I updated my question to provide an example of what my objects are.

Comment: @Zonko: a good refactoring option might also be to avoid passing the actual `bigObject` to the `Foo` class entirely, and to abstract all functionality needed by `Foo` through one or more interfaces. This should make `Foo` follow [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), and should make it easier for testing since you don't need to mock the entire `bigObject`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this argument applies to your use case, but option 1 invites inconsistencies. Someone (even you) might pass resource values that are incompatible with each other. If you rely on any kind of relationship between `bigObject` and the resources, definitely use option 2.

In any case, I'd say that a clean and compact interface is more important than the complexity of the unit tests.

To make your unit testing easier, couldn't you derive from `Bar` and give the derived class a constructor that takes the three resources? Then you could do something like this:

```
var myObject = new Foo(TestBar(res1, res2, res3));
```

Comment: using a derived object for testing is actually equivalent to mock calls to functions.